# Why does my job control fail inside a loop?

Tags: bash, job-control, jobs

My bash script is supposed to start a process (let's say, run `less`) and bring it back to foreground every time the process is suspended (e.g. by pressing `CTRL-Z`).

If I just keep repeating the commands, it works as expected:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -m
echo foo | less
# (User presses CTRL+Z to suspend the process)
echo "going back..."
sleep 1
fg
# (User presses CTRL+Z to suspend the process)
echo "going back..."
sleep 1
fg
# ... etc.
```

However, it fails inside a loop:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -m
echo foo | less
while true; do
    echo "going back..."
    sleep 1
    fg
done
```

Why does the second script exit the second time I suspend `less` and not keep looping? Am I missing a side effect of what loops in bash do?

Comment: [Answer #2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/464871/70524): "Bash chooses -- and has always chosen -- to break out of loops when a job is stopped. Continuing the loop is rarely what you want." And like [answer #1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/245691/70524) suggests, this works correctly in zsh.

Comment: @muru Excellent, thanks for pointing to that.